# Send Windows 10 Notification from Windows Service

Tags: notifications, windows-services, windows-10

I can find code on how to fire a Windows 10 notification from an Universal Windows App, or a remote notification from a cloud server, but I can't see how to make one from a background Windows Service.

Is this possible to be made?

Answer (score 1):

> > "Is this possible to be made?"

If you want to push notifications from background task. The answer is yes.

You would need to know some background task knowledge in UWP. Please read this document for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/guidelines-for-background-tasks

And you would need to used the suitable trigger to fire the background task.

Then in background task, you could push notification. Please follow this sample (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications) to learn how to send notification in UWP.

Here, you might need to notice one point, you would need to specify "Application Id" to the specific method when you send notification in background task. You could find the "Application Id" by using "View Code" with "Package.appxmanifest".

For example:`ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier("AppId").Show(toast);`

Then if you want to send notification from your cloud service, this document would be that you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview

Comment: I am not sure we are talking about the same thing... I am looking for a Service not a Background Task. A service is a program that runs on its own, a background task is like a thread fired from an app. My service will start in windows startup and schedule to run every minute.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such service for you to do it in UWP.

Comment: Hi @XavierXie-MSFT, is it possible for the background service to get notification for a user action on the toast as well? For example, if a toast was launched with two buttons and a text field, can the background service get notified with the text content of that text field if the first button is clicked, and another message if the second buttons is clicked? There won't be any UWP app associated with this task, it will be strictly a background task which will constantly run in the background as a service.